# Regex Negative Lookahead for Chrome & Safari

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I need to match Safari browsers, but not Chrome browsers using one Regex. I usually don't have a problem with regex, but negative look-aheads are stumping me here.

```
/(?!chrome)(safari)/i.test("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.56 Safari/536.5");
```

Can't figure out why this is returning `true`.

Comment: You're matching a substring `safari` which is not equal to `chrome`. (Not very meaningful if I understand it correctly.)

Comment: Hmm, I'm probably misinterpreting the use. I'm trying to have the string match safari, but only if the string doesn't match chrome.

Comment: [Negative lookahead:](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `q(?!u)` matches a `q` that is *not* followed by a `u`. That won't help here. You actually need a negative lookbehind for this job (string contains `Safari` that is not preceded by `Chrome`) but JS does not support negative lookbehind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will do it

```
^(?!.*chrome).*(safari)
```

BTW JavaScript does not support lookbehind but I see no problem with lookahead.

What you are saying with

```
(?!chrome)(safari)
```

Is that right before "safari" (zero width so starting with the cursor before s) there cannot be the string "chrome" which doesn't make sense.

Comment: That works, thanks! Makes sense. Another example I had seen through my understanding off.

Comment: Look-behind is supported in Firefox and Chrome now, but not Safari yet: https://caniuse.com/?search=lookbehind%20regex